# AppendChild not working in Ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, innerhtml, appendchild

I have a script to add an input field element when a current one is pressed. When i use innerHTML it replaces the current, which is not what i want. So I figured appendChild should add and not replace, but its not working. Heres my script..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addfile()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("org_div1").appendChild = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","addfile.php");
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And my html content..

```
<div id="org_div1" class="file_wrapper_input">

                        <input type="hidden" value="1" id="theValue" />
<input type="file" class="fileupload" name="file1" size=
"80" onchange="addfile()" /></div>
```

And my addfile.php file..

```
    var i=0;
        var ni = document.getElementById('org_div1');
        var numi = document.getElementById('theValue');
        var num = (document.getElementById('theValue').value -1)+ 2;
        numi.value = num;
        var divIdName = num;
</script>
<input type="file"  class="fileupload" size="80" name="file' + (num) + '" onchange="addfile()" />;
```

Any input? Again, innerHTML DOES work, appendChild does not. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

parent.appendChild() is a function waiting for DomNode Object and you are passing a String, it can't work...

Try :

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.innerHtml = xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("org_div1").appendChild(d);
```

Comment: Tried it, here the error i get `Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMHTMLDivElement.appendChild]"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://192.168.1.42/~jak2234/new_form/ :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 55"  data: no]`

Answer (score 0):

AppendChild expects an object, where innerHTML works with a String. And since your server returns partial HTML, this will only work with innerHTML.

Comment: @DariuszR Oh i see. Is there away for the server to convert the addfile.php from a string to an object?

Comment: But it will erase all existing html in parent

Comment: You will need a JavaScript object, where one can only build it in the browser (not the server). So you could convert your html to JSON, but you would still need to create DIV,INPUT and other objects on the client site. And yes - it will replace existing html...

Comment: @DariuszR @ChristopheCVB i created a follow up question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736528/using-ajax-request-to-create-element-and-appendchild